# Attempting to create new app on beta4 gives me rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new rails app to follow a book I'm working from and I'd like to use rails 5.0.0.beta4 so I match what is used in the text.

Every time I create a new app though when I check "rails -v" inside my project directory it reports back 5.0.0.rc1, but my gemfile says beta4.

And when I start the server the boiler page for the new rails app also says I'm running "5.0.0.rc1".  So I don't know what to believe.

What gives?  I even tried forcing the rails version using the command "rails *5.0.0.beta4* new myapp" but I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... Why? [The differences between `beta4` and `rc1`](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/f7a9860...fbdcf52) are going to be extremely minimal; mainly just very subtle bug fixes. It's *very* unlikely that your code will behave any differently from the book. I'd suggest you just use `rc1` anyway.

When you create a new rails project with rails version `5.0.0.beta4` installed, the following line in your `Gemfile` is created:

```
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta4', '< 5.1'
```

This is why `rc1` is being favoured over `beta4`. If you really want to force `beta4` to be used, then replace this line with:

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.beta4'
```

Then run `bundle update`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it's not so much that it's critical I had that version, but it was not the behavior I expected to get and I wanted to understand why.